# Why does my external stylesheet isn't working

Tags: html, css

Im new to this website and in web designing as well

Im currently working on a registration form that requires us to link an external stylesheet to an html. I used internal stylesheet at first and it's working but after I transferred it to the external and it's not working anymore.

I checked and both of my html and css are on the same folder.Inside, my css code has its own folder named css and my external stylesheet is named external_registration.css
Pls help me

css code here:

```
body{
            background-image: url('Images/Background.jpg');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-size: 100% 100%;
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        }
        .registration-box{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        .reg-box-wrapper{
            width: 50%;
            height: 150%;
            background: white;
            padding: 40px;
            border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px ;
            box-shadow: 0px 12px 13px #00000021;
        
        }

        .title-form, .login-image{
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .title-form a{
            text-transform: uppercase;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #999;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin: 0 10px;
        }

        .title-form a.active, .login-menu a:hover{
            color: #111;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #62cff6;
        }

        .login-image img{
            height: 130px;
        }

        input[type="name"] {
            border: none;
            background: #f0f0f0;
            weight: 40%;
            height: 8%;
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        input[type="phone"], input[type="email"] {
        
            border: none;
            background: #f0f0f0;
            weight: 40%;
            height: 8%;
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            width: 60%;
            margin: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            
        }
        input[type="submit"]{
            margin-top: 20px;
            background: #112C21;
            border: none;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 15px 70px;
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
            box-shadow: 0px 7px 9px #62cff66e;
        }

        input[type="submit"]:hover{
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        
       .select-css {
            display: block;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-weight: 700;
            color: #444;
            line-height: 1.3;
            padding: .6em 1.4em .5em .8em;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 100%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: 5px;
            margin-bottom:10px;
            border: 1px solid #aaa;
            box-shadow: 0 1px 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.04);
            border-radius: .5em;
            -moz-appearance: none;
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;
            background-color: #fff;
            background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22292.4%22%20height%3D%22292.4%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23007CB2%22%20d%3D%22M287%2069.4a17.6%2017.6%200%200%200-13-5.4H18.4c-5%200-9.3%201.8-12.9%205.4A17.6%2017.6%200%200%200%200%2082.2c0%205%201.8%209.3%205.4%2012.9l128%20127.9c3.6%203.6%207.8%205.4%2012.8%205.4s9.2-1.8%2012.8-5.4L287%2095c3.5-3.5%205.4-7.8%205.4-12.8%200-5-1.9-9.2-5.5-12.8z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E'),
              linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%);
            background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
            background-position: right .7em top 50%, 0 0;
            background-size: .65em auto, 100%;
        }
        
        .select-css::-ms-expand {
            display: none;
        }
        
        .select-css:hover {
            border-color: #888;
        }
        
        .select-css:focus {
            border-color: #aaa;
            box-shadow: 0 0 1px 3px rgba(59, 153, 252, .7);
            box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px -moz-mac-focusring;
            color: #222;
            outline: none;
        }
        
        input[type='radio']:after {
            width: 15px;
            height: 15px;
            border-radius: 15px;
            top: -2px;
            left: -1px;
            position: relative;
            background-color: #d1d3d1;
            content: '';
            display: inline-block;
            visibility: visible;
            border: 2px solid white
        }
        
        input[type='radio']:checked:after {
            width: 15px;
            height: 15px;
            border-radius: 15px;
            top: -2px;
            left: -1px;
            position: relative;
            background-color: #112C21;
            content: '';
            display: inline-block;
            visibility: visible;
            border: 2px solid white;
        }

        .select-css option {
            font-weight:normal;
        }
```

html code here:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registration</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="Newly hired" content="Registration Form">
    <title> Registration Form </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="external_registration.css"/>
    
</head>

<body>

    <div class="registration-box">
        <div class="reg-box-wrapper">
            <div class="title-form">
                <h2>Registration Form</h2>
            </div>
            <form>  
                <label for="name">Full name *</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Last name, First Namek" required>
                <label for="name">Location *</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="House/Building/Street Number, Street Name
                    Barangay/District Name, City/Municipality" required>
                    
                    <div style= "float:left;">
                        <label for="email">Email Address * </label>
                        <input type="email" style="width: 100px" placeholder="@example.com" required>
                    </div>
                    <div style= "float:left;">
                    <label for="phone_number">Phone number *</label>
                    <input type="phone" placeholder= "0XX-XXX-YYYY" required><br><br>
                    </div>
                    <br><br><br><br><br>
                    <label for="department">Department *</label>
                    <select class="select-css" name="Department" id="Department" required>
                        <option value=""> </option>
                        <option value="Animation Department">Animation</option>
                        <option value="Concept Planning Department">Concept Planning</option>                       
                        <option value="Character and Background Art Department">Character and Background Art </option>                  
                        <option value="Storyboard and Layout Department">Storyboard and Layout</option>                     
                        <option value="Marketing Department">Marketing and Management</option>      
                    </select>
                    <label for="gender">Gender:</label><br>
                        <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male">
                    <label for="male">Male</label><br>
                        <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">
                    <label for="female">Female</label><br>
                        <input type="radio" id="other" name="gender" value="other">
                    <label for="other">Other</label><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
             
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: is your html file and `external_registration.css ` in same folder ??

Comment: You mentioned your CSS is in css folder. In that case your path should be css/external_registration.css. Make sure your path is correct. Share your folder structure for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell the code where the CSS is with a folder name.
If it is inside a subfolder then declare it like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/external_registration.css"/>
```

If it is one folder up, then use ".." before the folder name.

Comment: Thank you :)) ! it worked when i tried <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/external_registration.css"/>

Comment: I'm glad it helped :D Learn more at [link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)